# Symfony 1.4 - AJAX requests prevent to auto logout a user

Tags: ajax, request, symfony1

I'm using Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine. I also use the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin and I want to use the 'auto logout' feature but it seems the AJAX requests on the site always overwrite the $this->lastRequest variable, therefore it is never going to reach the 'timeout' value and the user never going to be logoutted...

```js
if (false !== $timeout && null !== $this - > lastRequest && time() - $this - > lastRequest >= $timeout) {
  if ($this - > options['logging']) {
    $this - > dispatcher - > notify(new sfEvent($this, 'application.log', array('Automatic user logout due to timeout')));
  }
  $this - > getGuardUser() - > setOnline(0);
  $this - > getGuardUser() - > save();
  $this - > setTimedOut();
  $this - > setAuthenticated(false);
}
```

So how can I ban to AJAX to overwrite the $this->lastRequest parameter??

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Your code does not show how is `$this->lastRequest` set.